# Is it possible to target a specific instance in a clustered environment with group policy?

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

Not sure where to ask this, but here goes:

I'm in a clustered environment, not the primary DBA (and he's not very AD/GP savvy either) and I'm being asked to set security permissions for an AD Service Account on a specific instance on a cluster that hosts multiple instances. Is that even a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

*<sub>Community Wiki answer generated from a comment on the question by [Steve Mangiameli](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/50728/steve-mangiameli)</sub>*

It is, but you'll need to be a little creative.  Remember, you will be setting two different permissions sets - OS and SQL Server.  Hopefully, each instance has install and DBs set in different directories, for each instance.  OS level permissions should be directed for the disks/directories for that instance.

SQL server permissions are relatively simple at that point.